# sbt assembly shading to create fat jar to run on spark

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, guava, grpc, sbt-assembly

I'm using sbt assembly to create a fat jar which can run on spark. Have dependencies on `grpc-netty`. Guava version on spark is older than the one required by `grpc-netty` and I run into this error: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206440/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkargument). I was able to resolve this by setting userClassPathFirst to true on spark, but leads to other errors.

Correct me if I am wrong, but from what I understand, I shouldn't have to set userClassPathFirst to true if I do shading correctly. Here's how I do shading now:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.guava.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.google.guava" % "guava" % "20.0")
    .inLibrary("io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % "1.1.2")
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.11",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.clapper" %% "argot" % "1.0.3",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % "1.1.2",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "20.0"
)
```

What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there. What `shadeRule` does is it [renames *class* names](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading), not library names:

> The main ShadeRule.rename rule is used to rename classes. All references to the renamed classes will also be updated.

In fact, in [`com.google.guava:guava`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/20.0) there are no classes with package `com.google.guava`:

```
$ jar tf ~/Downloads/guava-20.0.jar  | sed -e 's:/[^/]*$::' | sort | uniq
META-INF
META-INF/maven
META-INF/maven/com.google.guava
META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava
com
com/google
com/google/common
com/google/common/annotations
com/google/common/base
com/google/common/base/internal
com/google/common/cache
com/google/common/collect
com/google/common/escape
com/google/common/eventbus
com/google/common/graph
com/google/common/hash
com/google/common/html
com/google/common/io
com/google/common/math
com/google/common/net
com/google/common/primitives
com/google/common/reflect
com/google/common/util
com/google/common/util/concurrent
com/google/common/xml
com/google/thirdparty
com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix
```

It should be enough to change your shading rule to this:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.google.guava" % "guava" % "20.0")
    .inLibrary("io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % "1.1.2")
)
```

So you don't need to change `userClassPathFirst`.

Moreover, you can simplify your shading rule like this:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "my_conf.@1").inAll
)
```

Since `org.apache.spark` dependencies are `provided`, they will not be included in your jar and will not be shaded (hence spark will use its own unshaded version of guava that it has on the cluster).