# How to fix the issue for error download encrypted files from GCS

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-storage

I develop app using scala for download encrypted file from GCS (encrypted file using customer-supplied encryption keys) by service account credentials on hdfs

```
val path = new Path(keyfile)

val fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri, spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

val storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder.setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(fs.open(path))).build.getService
```

I found the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)
```

Comment: This is probably related to a conflict of Guava versions (2 dependencies depending on different versions of Guava). Can you show us the dependency tree (included and excluded dependencies)?

Comment: Can you show us complete error information and dependencies? [You may also check similar error question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206440/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkargument)

Answer (score 0):

A NoSuchMethodError occurs when we’re calling a method that does not exist at runtime, The method must have existed at compile time.

Verify the dependency versions.
Try to find out where the method is being called.