# "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, char, java.lang.Object)'

Tags: java, grpc-java, protobuf-java

I am getting this error, even after trying different versions of jars available and unable to find the `Preconditions` class in my intelliJ workspace.
Not sure why this method is getting called. I'm getting this runtime exception every time i run the code.
I am trying grpc and protobuffers for the first time but I'm not sure what to do about the below error.

> ```
> "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
> 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(  
>          boolean, java.lang.String, char, java.lang.Object)'
> ```

My **dependencies** look like this:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.29.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.49.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And my **mvn dependency:tree o/p is below**.

```
[INFO] +- io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.29.0:compile (version selected from constraint [1.29.0,1.29.0])
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.29.0:compile (version selected from constraint [1.29.0,1.29.0])
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.android:annotations:jar:4.1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.perfmark:perfmark-api:jar:0.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-grpclb:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile (version selected from constraint [4.1.48.Final,4.1.48.Final])
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:1.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-services:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-testing:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.24.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.grpc:grpc-xds:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.grpc:grpc-alts:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk-uber:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.20.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.34.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.10:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:jar:0.24.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.34.0:compile
[INFO] |     |        \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.opencensus:opencensus-proto:jar:0.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.29.0:compile (version selected from constraint [1.29.0,1.29.0])
[INFO] +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.8:compile
[INFO] \- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.49.Final:compile
```

I have checked the existing posts as well on this issue but none seems to be working for me. I believe there might be some issue with the versions but all the versions seem to be giving this error only.

Comment: I have absolutely no knowledge with gprc, but [this similar QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206440/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkargument) uses version `23.6-jre` of guava, and it is already more than two years old. Can you use newer versions?

Comment: used - 29.0-jre,still not working

Comment: Then I cannot help further, sorry. But I'd advise you to reduce your code to a [mcve] - either you'll figure it out in the process or somebody on here will be better able to help you with it when you post that

Answer (score 4):

Problem with a 3rd Party Library:

```
"main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(  
         boolean, java.lang.String, char, java.lang.Object)'
```

Let's try to update guava

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
```