# NoSuchMethodError gRPC

Tags: grpc, minecraft, consul, grpc-java

I´m using gRPC with consul to communicate with a microservice. This error occures when I load this as a plugin in spigot1.8.8. First i thought is some issue with Clashpath so i relocated it. But got still the same error (with different packages). This is my Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:742) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:750) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:668) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:959) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:954) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:705) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:701) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java:81) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.<init>(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:174) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:149) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:27) ~[?:?]
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:76) ~[?:?]
        at net.rangemc.service.common.consul.ConsulChannelProvider.get(ConsulChannelProvider.java:23) ~[?:?]
        at net.range.service.user.client.consul.ConsulGrpcUserClientProvider.get(ConsulGrpcUserClientProvider.java:30) ~[?:?]
        at net.rangemc.service.user.spigot.UserSpigotClient.onEnable(UserSpigotClient.java:23) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:357) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:317) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:414) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:378) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:333) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:263) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:525) [spigot-1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_275]
```

Hopefully someone can help me. This issue doesn´t exist running it with velocity.
I already tried different guava versions

Comment: The problem is certainly Guava being downgraded. That method was added in Guava 20. The exception is not using a relocated Guava. You may want to post your relocation configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt that's caused by guava jar conflict; Please reference [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) to add required dependencies like this:

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.38.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.38.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.38.0'
compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53' // necessary for Java 9+
```

And there has a same question [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206440/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkargument)
;

Please check the guava version after startup, I guess some of dependency has a lower version which contains guava, after exclude this version, it should be work.